# Find limit: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \cos\frac an \right)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits, approximation

**EDIT:** since the proposed below "property" is incorrect in general, one can solve the limit by exponentiating the function.

---

When investigating this limit
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \cos\frac an \right)^n$$

I have found a property that allows to find the limit pretty easy:
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} (f(x)-1) \cdot g(x)}$$

Then a rule of derivative for $\left(\frac 00\right)$ limits is applied to get $1$ as an answer.

However, I have not been able to find any name or reference to the property above. Does anyone have a link to this property? or its name? If it is non-valid one, what's the approach to use for such a limit?

Comment: This property is true due to continuity of $\exp$ function

Comment: What you are trying to prove is not true, not even for constants. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: @egor-ivanov, this part is clear, but where does $(f(x)-1)$ come from?
isn't it $exp(g(x) \ln f(x))$ instead?

Comment: That formula assumes that $\lim_{x\to\infty }f(x)=1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, which is the case here. My memory aid: consider $$f(x)=1+\frac1x,\qquad g(x)=x,$$ when we know the limit of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ to be equal to $e$.

Comment: @bag_dush if $f\to 0$ when $x\to 0$, then $\lim \ln f = \lim \ln (1 + (f-1))$ due to $\lim \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$

Comment: In some courses it was informally called "EALLA".

Comment: $\log \cos \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right) =  - \frac{{a^2 }}{2}\frac{1}{{n^2 }} + \mathcal{O}_a \!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^4 }}} \right)$ as $n\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't immediately find this with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim%20f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5E%7Bg%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%7D%24&p=1), so I promote the comment to an answer. Will delete, when a proper duplicate target is found.

---

The OP (or their teacher) apparently is wont for using the rule
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-1)g(x)},
$$
but forgot to include all the relevant assumptions. Namely that this rule is designed to ONLY handle indeterminate limits of the type $1^\infty$.

The justification for that formula comes from the well-known limits
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}(1+\frac1x)^x=e.
$$
A crude argument is thus to write $f(x)=1+h(x)$, when $h(x)\to0$, and
$$
f(x)^{g(x)}=(1+h(x))^{g(x)}=\left((1+h(x))^{1/h(x)}\right)^{h(x)g(x)}.
$$
Under the given assumptions $|1/h(x)|\to\infty$, so the base of the formula on the r.h.s. $\to e$, and the claim follows from the continuity of the exponential function.

---

My personal memory aid is, indeed, that of $h(x)=1/x$, $g(x)=x$.

My personal favorite application of this rule is the following proof for the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}(2^{1/x}-1)x=\ln 2.
$$
This is seen by the choices $f(x)=2^{1/x}\to1$ and $g(x)=x\to\infty$ when obviously
$f(x)^{g(x)}=2\to2$. This time we use the formula to find the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x)-1)g(x)$$
using the known (!!) $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)^{g(x)}$ :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Approach0, also known as ApproachZero, is a LaTeX-capable search engine covering Math.SE and AOPS (so in some ways better than Google). Sorry about not including a link right away, which may have confused you.

Comment: Hi, I am happy to find new things. I not knew of this website. It is a engine of reaserch :-). Good news. +1 from this morning.

Comment: No problem, @Sebastiano. I appreciate you going through my post.

Answer (score 4):

What you wrote is not true. Set $f$ to be a constant function equal to $2$, and $g$ to be a constant function equal to $1$.

Then, $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)^{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} 2^1 = 2 \neq e =e^{ \lim_{x\to 0}(2-1)\cdot 1} = e^{\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} (f(x)-1) \cdot g(x)}$$

However, if $f$ is strictly positive, then what is true is that.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{\lim_\limits{x\to 0} g(x)\cdot \ln(f(x))}$$

This is simply because

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)^{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\ln\left(f(x)^{g(x)}\right)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{g(x)\cdot \ln(f(x))} = e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} g(x)\cdot \ln(f(x))}$$

Comment: that's what my question is about: if this property sth known, cause I have not seen it anywhere. 

so, if it is not true, what's the approach to use for this limit?

Comment: @bag_dush The "property" is not a property, because it is not true. Even if it "works" on your particular example, that does in no way mean it is correct.

Comment: @5xum I was taught this formula as an undergrad. Fortunately, it was also explained that it ONLY APPLIES to the indeterminate form $1^\infty$. Your example doesn't refute that because you don't have $\lim f(x)=1$. If your point was that the OP forgot to include that assumption, then all is fine.

Comment: I agree with Jyrki, this is an undergrad formula which holds given appropriate assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

the property is true only if you have an indeterminate form !
If not, just pass to the limit ! And $\lim_02^1=2^1$.
When there is no problem there is no problem !

A problem arise when $\lim f=1$ **and** $\lim g=\infty$ because $f^g=e^{g\ln f}$ and the exponent is $\infty\times0$.

If so, $\ln(f)\sim(f-1)$ (another way to say $\ln(1+x)\sim x$) and then the exponent $\sim(f-1)g$.
This equivalent is an extremly powerfull tool as is $f(x)-f(a)\sim_a(x-a)f'(a)$ (just another way to read the definition of the dérivative).

I can give another example

Find $\qquad\displaystyle\lim_1\Big({\alpha+t\over\alpha+1}\Big)^{{t\over1-t}}$ !

The exponent equal $E={t\over1-t}\ln\Big({\alpha+t\over\alpha+1}\Big)$.
The  interior of the $\ln$ tends to 1, therefore
$\ln\Big({\alpha+t\over\alpha+1}\Big)\sim{\alpha+t\over\alpha+1}-1={t-1\over\alpha+1}$,
$E\sim-{t\over\alpha+1}\sim-{\alpha\over\alpha+1}$
and the limit
$\ell=e^{-{\alpha\over\alpha+1}}$

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:** by using the property of continuity of exponent let's rewrite the limit as:
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \cos\frac an \right)^n = e^{\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}( n \cdot \ln(\cos\frac an))}$$

Then considering the power itself: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}( n \cdot \ln(\cos\frac an)) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\ln(\cos\frac an)}{\frac1n} = \mbox{L'Hôpital's rule} = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{-\frac{\sin \frac an}{\cos \frac an} \cdot (-a/n^2)}{- 1/n^2} = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} - a \tan \frac an = 0$

**Answer:** $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \cos\frac an \right)^n = e^{0} = 1$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)-1\to0$ then $\log(f(x))=\log(1+f(x)-1)=f(x)-1+O((f(x)-1)^2)$.

Then $f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp(g(x)\log(f(x)))=\exp(g(x)(f(x)-1)+O(g(x)(f(x)-1)^2))$.

Thus if $g(x)(f(x)-1)^2\to0$ then $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}=\lim\exp(g(x)(f(x)-1))$.

So it seems you need both $f(x)-1\to0$ and $g(x)(f(x)-1)^2\to0$ but then you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [SmileyCraft](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4857911/505767) answer, we are using that for $f(x)\to 1$ and $g(x)\to \infty$

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)^{g(x)}\stackrel{\text{identity}}=\lim_{x\to x_0}e^{g(x)\log f(x)}=\lim_{x\to x_0}e^{(f(x)-1)g(x)}$$

indeed

$$g(x)\log f(x)=g(x)\log \left(1+(f(x)-1)\right)=g(x)(f(x)-1)\frac{\log \left(1+(f(x)-1)\right)}{f(x)-1}$$

with $t=f(x)-1\to 0$ and $\frac{\log(1+t)}t \to 1$.

Comment: Hi. I Have not understood $\lim_{x\to x_0}e^{g(x)\log f(x)}=\lim_{x\to x_0}e^{(f(x)-1)g(x)}$. Why? Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano As indicated $f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\log f(x)}$ is an  identity while$ \lim_{x\to x_0}e^{g(x)\log f(x)}=\lim_{x\to x_0}e^{(f(x)-1)g(x)}$ holds only in the limit using that $\frac{\log(1+t)}t \to 1$. Of course $\lim_{x\to x_0}e^{(f(x)-1)g(x)}$ is simpler but we need the previous identity to prove it.